# Does adding live chat script to a website affect its SEO?

Tags: seo, javascript

I have a client who has added a live chat script just before his /body tag. The live chat script uses WebSockets for communication with servers. However, it appears his SEO traffic decreased by a good margin after the addition. Can live chat script be the reason it happened?

I understand that the question finally drills down to 'Does script tag affect SEO?' but was trying to give as much context as possible.

This appears to have happened in first week of January. If the above is not the reason, have there been any changes to Google ranking algorithms recently?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I think your question has been downvote because your question is unclear or poorly formed, so although the question might be a good question appears to be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely. The only scenario that I could see where it could affect it is if the chat script caused a big increase in the page load time. Even that would not have had the type of immediate affect you are talking about. Google is constantly updating their index and often make algorithmic changes that could affect the site. I would look at either external factors (google updates) or internal factors other than the script (content or structural changes) that could have affected it. 
If you think it was the script, you can always remove it and see if the rankings come back.

Answer (score 0):

Using live chat application might actually increase your search engine rankings, i.e. it increases convenience (so users are more likely to stay on your site), it might bring more sale, interest, more traffic and a higher website ranking. It's also a good inspiration for creating new content. More you can find here: http://www.seoblog.com/2014/03/live-chat-website-actually-help-rankings/.

Comment: Your user name indicates that you may have some affiliation with live chat product.    If so, it would be good to disclose that when answering questions related to live chat.

Comment: This link appears to be relevant to the question, and helps answer it.   However, a link only answer is not  high quality.   It would be more useful to summarize the major points from the article here.   That way users don't have to click unless they need lots of details.

Comment: Hi Stephen, you are right, I've just edited the post. Hope you find it more useful and interesting.